# Bind dynamically-sized 2D-data to grid from xaml

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, binding, grid

For example, I have an object like this: `data2D = List<List<string>>`. I want to bind it to the grid with `data2D.Count` rows and `data2D[LongestSubList].Count` columns.

`data2D.Count` and `data2D[LongestSubList].Count` could be changed by business logic so grid's number of rows and cols should be changed either.

From code I can manage that and I can bind/unbind each `data2D[i][j]` to corresponding cell on element add/remove, but is there a way to do it from xaml?